# Passing a cause description to a 403 handler view

Tags: django

I want to show an informative error message to a user hitting a page that results in a 403 Forbidden. I'm using Django 1.8.

My idea of passing an error message is this:

```
# in a view
if not ...:
  raise PermissionDenied('You have no power here')
```

Then somewhere in the `handler403` view, I'd like to retrieve the message (or maybe even a structured object) and render an informative page based on it.

Though the handler seems to only receive the request object and the template name.

Is there a way to pass a custom message to the handler? (Of course I could assign a custom attribute to the request object before raising the exception, and hope that the same object will be passed to the handler, but this feels like a hack.)

**Update:** Indeed there is a middleware for that already: [`contrib/messages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/) is capable of piggybacking messages on the request object, and more.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you would have to implement this using a middleware:

```
class ExceptionMiddleware:
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if exception.args:
            request.message = exception.args[0]
```

Then in your `handler403` you could access `request.message`.

Obviously you could flesh-out this middleware to allow passing more than just a message to the view.

Comment: Nice! I wonder if a middleware like this is already implemented somewhere in contrib.

Comment: OTOH this is still patching the request object, just in a centralized way.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's significantly cleaner than explicitly patching `request` *and* raising an exception in every case.

Comment: You could also use `contrib.messages` to store a message in the session (either from your view or a middleware), then have your `handler403` display queued messages... But that seems unnecessary- nothing wrong with patching `request` (IMHO).